# Find all the matched list in lists of lists

Tags: r, list, match, element

I have a list of vectors
I want to find all the common vectors. That is, those that contain exactly the same elements, keeping the position number of each list in R. One liner command if possible.

Here is mylist:

```
mylist<-list(c("yes", "no"), c("no", "other", "up", 
"down"), c("no", "yes"), c("no", 
"yes"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", 
"yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"))
```

Desired output:

Common lists are: match 1: 1,3,4
                  match 2: 5,6,7

Comment: I hope I fixed it @lmo

Comment: A straightforward alternative is `ml2 = lapply(mylist, sort); match(ml2, unique(ml2))`

Comment: @alexis_laz your solution do not provide the position of the matched lists for each match! check  akrun answer. Thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using `split`

```
Filter(function(x) length(x) >1, split(seq_along(mylist),
                     sapply(mylist, function(x) toString(sort(x)))))
#$`maybe, no, yes`
#[1] 5 6 7

#$`no, yes`
#[1] 1 3 4
```

Comment: Can you write some comments, how this is working exactly? thanks Akron!

Comment: @EliasEstatisticsEU  The idea is to `split` the sequence of 'mylist' by a group of `vector` created by pasting the `sort`ed elements of the 'mylist' and then `Filter` the `list` of sequence having length that is greater than 1.

Comment: Filter(function(x) condition_to_use_as_filter, some_results_to_filter) - It has a weird syntax, I think! normally, someone it may expected a syntax such as: Filter(some_results_tofilter, function(x) condition-for_filtering). Am I Wrong?

Comment: @EliasEstatisticsEU  I think you are comparing it with `lapply`, `sapply` syntax.  This is a bit different and can be compared to `Map/mapply` syntax where the argument comes after the anonymous function call.

Answer (score 4):

`duplicated` accepts lists as its main argument. So you could use

```
which(duplicated(mylist1) | duplicated(mylist1, fromLast=TRUE))
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

for your first example. Note that this will not distinguish between groups of list elements with common elements, but will only return TRUE for elements with identical elements.

For the second example dataset, you can use the following to find positions of the groups

```
# get group values as integers
groups <- as.integer(factor(sapply(mylist2,
                                   function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))))
# return list of groups
lapply(seq_len(max(groups)), function(x) which(x == groups))
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 4
```

**data**

```
mylist1 <- 
list(c("yes", "no"), c("no", "other", "up", "down"), c("no", 
"yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"
), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"))

mylist2 <-
list(c("yes", "no"), c("no", "other", "up", "down"), c("no", 
"yes"), c("no", "yes"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", 
"maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"))
```

Comment: I want to distinguish between matches, see updated question. thanks

Comment: @EliasEstatisticsEU Please avoid posting moving target questions. It may be quite frustrating to spend time on an answer which suddenly becomes invalid after an edit (and possibly even unfairly downvoted, as here). Please take your time to think carefully about your problem _before_ posting. Cheers.

Comment: This is a very neat answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is one for fun. You can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` package to get the following data frame,

```
d1 <- qdapTools::mtabulate(mylist)
d1
#  down maybe no other up yes
#1    0     0  1     0  0   1
#2    1     0  1     1  1   0
#3    0     0  1     0  0   1
#4    0     0  1     0  0   1
#5    0     1  1     0  0   1
#6    0     1  1     0  0   1
#7    0     1  1     0  0   1
```

And then you can split it by pasting,

```
l1 <- split(d1, do.call(paste, d1))

l1
#$`0 0 1 0 0 1`
#  down maybe no other up yes
#1    0     0  1     0  0   1
#3    0     0  1     0  0   1
#4    0     0  1     0  0   1

#$`0 1 1 0 0 1`
#  down maybe no other up yes
#5    0     1  1     0  0   1
#6    0     1  1     0  0   1
#7    0     1  1     0  0   1

#$`1 0 1 1 1 0`
#  down maybe no other up yes
#2    1     0  1     1  1   0
```

You can utilize that list however you want, i.e.

```
lapply(l1, rownames)
#$`0 0 1 0 0 1`
#[1] "1" "3" "4"

#$`0 1 1 0 0 1`
#[1] "5" "6" "7"

#$`1 0 1 1 1 0`
#[1] "2"
```

Or even,

```
setNames(lapply(l1, rownames), lapply(l1, function(i)toString(names(i)[i[1,] == 1])))
#$`no, yes`
#[1] "1" "3" "4"

#$`maybe, no, yes`
#[1] "5" "6" "7"

#$`down, no, other, up`
#[1] "2"
```

Comment: After creating "d1" (which, by the way, can be simply created as `d1 = table(rep(1:length(mylist), lengths(mylist)), unlist(mylist))`), to avoid coercions and `paste`ing, groups can be created with `d1 %*% (2 ^ (0:(ncol(d1) - 1)))` to split by

Comment: @alexis_laz thanks for the suggestions. I don't get how that grouping code works (or actually doesn't - throws an error)...but I mean the logic behind it

Comment: It basically converts each row to an integer following kind of a binary -> decimal approach. It's a fancier alternative of `apply(d1, 1, function(x) sum(x * (2^(0:(length(x) - 1)))))`; it's being posted every now and then here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
mylist<-list(c("yes", "no"), c("no", "other", "up", 
                               "down"), c("no", "yes"), c("no", 
                                                          "yes"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", 
                                                                                             "yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"))

library(dplyr)

# function to create a dataframe from your list. Might not be the most efficient way to do this.
f <- function(data) {
  nCol <- max(vapply(data, length, 0))
  data <- lapply(data, function(row) c(row, rep(NA, nCol-length(row))))
  data <- matrix(unlist(data), nrow=length(data), ncol=nCol, byrow=TRUE)
  data.frame(data)
}

# create a dataframe from the list, and add a 'key' column
df = f(mylist)
df$key = apply( df , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" )

# find the total times the key occurs
df_total = df %>% group_by(key) %>% summarise(n =n())

# find the indices that belong to the groups
result = lapply(df_total$key, function(x) which(df$key==x))
```

Result:

```
> result
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even though it works, I cannot accept it as an accepted answer cause it is not one -liner.  Thanks for your answer F Maas

Comment: Why is a one-liner required?

Comment: This solution is indeed much less nice than the others. Good motivation to keep on learning and improve my R skills ;)

Comment: I Dont know however which is fastest one and requiring less memory!

Answer (score 1):

data

```
mylist <- list(c("yes", "no"), c("no", "other", "up", "down"), c("no", "yes"), 
           c("no", "yes"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), c("no", "yes", "maybe"), 
           c("no", "yes", "maybe"))
```

a (long) one-liner

```
sapply(unique(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " ")))), function(y) which(y == unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " ")))))
```

output:

```
$`no yes`
[1] 1 3 4

$`down no other up`
[1] 2

$`maybe no yes`
[1] 5 6 7
```

Comment: Bravo that you made it! (greek geek?)

Comment: yes elias I'm greek(y), i hope the oneliner will help.